# How can I display elements in the linked list without using function in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to display elements in the linked list without using function in C++. My code does not appear anything on the screen, even it does not contains any errors. I do not know how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Element {
    int data;
    Element *next;
};

struct List {
    int nb_ele;
    Element *head;
    Element *tail;
};

int main(){
    Element *tmp;

    tmp = new(Element);
    tmp ->data = 5;
    tmp ->next = NULL;

    List *li;
    li ->head = tmp;
    li ->tail = tmp;
    li ->nb_ele = 1;

    tmp = new(Element);
    tmp ->data = 7;
    tmp ->next = li->head;
    li ->head = tmp;
    li ->nb_ele = li->nb_ele + 1;

    Element *ptr;
    ptr = li->head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        cout<< ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `List *li;  li ->head = tmp`. --> `li` is an uninitialized pointer. What are you expecting to get from `li->head` ?

Comment: ... and why are you addressing the problem this way? "_without using function_" - I don't even know what it means but it sounds like programming with your hands tied behind your back. What's the purpose?

Comment: I write li -> head, because I think I can get access the pointer head in the structure list. And then it will get the address of the element name tmp

Comment: I just want to get some fundamental ideas before moving to code in the function since it's a little bit complicated for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
List *li;
```

li is an uninitialized pointer and when you try to access it later, causes problems.
change this line to:

```
List *li = new List;
```

or don't use a pointer. simply change it to:

```
List li;
```